# Why Firebase user is not authenticated anymore when refreshing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

A very simple App. At the `/` path I want to render `Home` when logged in and  `Introduction` if not signed in. Logging in on the Login page works, if i console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser) it shows all the data and on `/` it renders `Home` correctly. So, while still being at the `/` path, something weird happens; when i refresh page we are not logged in anymore and it renders `Introduction`. But when I click on the link `<li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>` the `Home` component renders correctly and we are logged in again. Why is this happening?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import firebase from './firebase'

import Home from './containers/home'
import Login from './containers/login'
import Register from './containers/register'
import Dashboard from './containers/dashboard'

const Protected = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
    if(firebase.auth().currentUser) 
      return <Component {...props} />
     else 
      return <Redirect to='/register' />

  }} />
)

const Introduction = props => ( <h1>hello</h1>)

class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <React.Fragment>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/register'>Register</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/login'>login</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/dashboard'>dashboard</Link></li>
          </ul>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact render={(props) => {
              if(firebase.auth().currentUser) 
                return <Home {...props} />
              else
                return <Introduction {...props} />
              }
            } />
            <Route path='/register' exact component={Register} />
            <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Protected path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happens:

- Webpage loads
- Firebase starts a request to check whether the user is authenticated
- The app renders, `currentUser` is null
- The authentication state changes, but the app doesn't re-render

The app needs to listen to changes in the authentication state and perform a re-render accordingly. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentUser: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(currentUser => {
      this.setState({ currentUser })
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  render() {
    // use this.state.currentUser
  }
}
```

Comment: This behavior is problematic if you are using authenticated routes and redirecting users to a login page. The app renders, current user is null, redirects to login page before firebase has a chance to initialize.

Comment: Not sure I understand. It might initially show a login page, but if the user is authenticated, the state will update and show the dashboard. What's your suggested alternative?

Comment: @kindaro I'm not aware of any solution (still looking) other than to wait for the login state before rendering anything in react. What you mentioned is fine (flash login page and then refresh to logged-in page after status) if it's a SPA, but if you are redirecting user to a separate login URL then it becomes a problem.